# Matter JS Pause physics but still interact with objects

Tags: javascript, canvas, game-physics, physics, matter.js

I'm looking to pause matter.js but still be able to manipulate objects. When I toggle runner.enabled, it disables all mouse constraints. I want to be able to pause the engine and move objects, then turn the physics back on. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to toggle IsStatic on your bodies.

To pause all objects you can run a for loop to set all your `bodies.body.isStatic` properties to `True`.

Then, on click event mouseDown you can do `this.body.isStatic = false;` and on mouseUp you can do `this.body.isStatic = true;`

This will allow you to manipulate your bodies and move them wherever you like until you do something like `bodies.forEach(body) body.isStatic = false` to allow your bodies to interact with your world again.

Keep in mind this WILL retain physics properties, so you'll also want to reset the bodies velocity and momentum, etc, properties to what they were prior to the pause at some point. Either on unPause or on mouseUp.

Comment: ah, great! I hadn't thought of that. I'll give it a try.

Comment: If it worked out for you can you please mark my answer as correct? Thank you